# Как в MySQL начать вывод с определенной строки в таблице?

Tags: mysql

Как в MySQL начать вывод с определенной строки в таблице?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LIMIT 390, 30
```

Выводим 30 записей начиная с 390 строки.